# visualization of Cayley graph in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, gap, cayley-graphs

I want to draw a Cayley graph of a group using GAP after I get a list. Is there a way to visualize that Cayley graph ?

Or  is there any other software to do it?

Comment: I think nearly all software can do this.  I use *Mathematica*.

Comment: A highly upvoted post at [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192570/how-to-visualize-a-cayley-graph-in-this-style) might give you an example of such illustrations.

Comment: I have use  Mathematica but it seem that it's working only for S the generator. I mean it's only for connected Cayley graph. My list in GAP is when the S is not the generator.